# PHP issue with date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I use a date format like (d.m.Y) and i store my date in database as text with value of format (d.m.Y) and when i need compare date with my date in database like: 10.01.2018 with today date 21.06.2017 they will say that first date was smaller.

I try use some different SQL query with `SELECT * FROM vpn_zahtijevi WHERE status='Aktivan' AND STR_TO_DATE(vpndatumend, '%d.%m.%Y') <=  STR_TO_DATE('$datum', '%d.%m.%Y') OR status='Provjera u tijeku' AND STR_TO_DATE(vpndatumend, '%d.%m.%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('$datum', '%d.%m.%Y')` and not work again...

What can i do to make it good? 
Can i change my time format in code or i need change all database format?
Witch way is best for date in PHP?

Comment: Do not store Dates as text. store it as a date

Comment: storing date in date format is good .not as text so only you can able to easily do  whatever you want do .  and also show your relevant code too

Comment: I am change my querstion with sql code

Answer (score 0):

you should compare both converted  values

```
select * from my_table 
where  STR_TO_DATE(vpndatumend, '%d.%m.%Y ') =  STR_TO_DATE('10.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y ')
```

Comment: what's mean "Its not working"   ...  you have error?   .. wrong result?.. no result? .. update you question add  real data sample, the expected  result and the query you are using .. (not working have no sense in coding)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store dates as text in the database, especially not when later comparison is necessary. All SQL databases have date(time) columns for this purpose.

Maybe you have a valid use case, but please elaborate on that specific use case to get the answer you are looking for ;)...